# If $x+y+z=3$, then $\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{x^2}{2y^2-y+3}\ge\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $x,y,z>0$, be such that $x+y+z=3$. Show  that
>   $$\dfrac{x^2}{2y^2-y+3}+\dfrac{y^2}{2z^2-z+3}+\dfrac{z^2}{2x^2-x+3}\ge\dfrac{3}{4}.$$

I've tried many things but all have failed.
$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\dfrac{x^2}{2y^2-y+3}\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}(2y^2-y+3)\right)\ge (x+y+z)^2=9.$$
But
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}(2y^2-y+3)=2\sum_{\text{cyc}}x^2+6\ge 12.$$

Comment: So, you tried CS and that didn't help.  What else have you contemplated?

Comment: brutal force works but ugly.:(

Comment: maybe have other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{2y^2-y+3}\geq\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2x^2y^2-x^2y+3x^2)}$. Thus, it remains to prove that $\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2x^2y^2-x^2y+3x^2)}\geq\frac{3}{4}$, which is $\sum\limits_{cyc}(3x^4-x^3y-2x^3z+x^2y^2-x^2yz)\geq0$, which is obvious.

Comment: why it is obvious?can you explain the key obvious? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Write $x= \frac{3a}{a+b+c}$, $y=\frac{3b}{a+b+c}$, $z=\frac{3c}{a+b+c}$ and substitute. Get the equivalent inequality:

\begin{eqnarray}
18 (a^6 +b^6+c^6) +  33 (a^5 b +b^5 c+  c^5a ) + 2 (a^4 b^2+ b^4 c^2 + c^4 a^2)-50(a^3 b^3 + b^3 c^3 + c^3 a^3)+\\  + 98 (a^2 b^4 + b^2 c^4 + c^2 a^4) + 9 (a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5) - 6 (a^4 b c + b^4 c a + c^4 a b )-\\ - 11( a^3 b^2 c + b^3 c^2 a + c^3 a^2 b)- 35(a^3 b c^2 + b^3 c a^2 + c^3 a b^2)- 174 a^2 b^2c^2    
    \ge 0
\end{eqnarray}
with $a$, $b$, $c >0$. The expression on the left hand side has circular symmetry. So we may assume that either $a\ge b\ge c >0$ or $0< a \le b \le c$. In the first case, substitute $c= u$, $b = u+v$, $a= u+v+w$ in the above expression and we get an expression in $u$, $v$, $w$ with all the coefficients positive, hence $\ge 0$. Similarly, in the second case use $a= u$, $b=u+v$, $c=u+v+w$, again getting on the LHS an expression in $u$,$v$,$w$ with all the coefficients positive.

$\bf{Added:}$

When performing the substitution $c= u$, $b = u+v$, $a= u+v+w$ we get
$$696 u^4 v^2 + 1774 u^3 v^3 + 1720 u^2 v^4 + 752 u v^5 + 128 v^6 + 
 696 u^4 v w + 2409 u^3 v^2 w + 2936 u^2 v^3 w + 1592 u v^4 w + 
 336 v^5 w + 696 u^4 w^2 + 2655 u^3 v w^2 + 3627 u^2 v^2 w^2 + 
 2226 u v^3 w^2 + 560 v^4 w^2 + 1010 u^3 w^3 + 2411 u^2 v w^3 + 
 1999 u v^2 w^3 + 648 v^3 w^3 + 574 u^2 w^4 + 913 u v w^4 + 
 437 v^2 w^4 + 150 u w^5 + 141 v w^5 + 18 w^6$$

while performing $a= u$, $b=u+v$, $c=u+v+w$ we get 
$$696 u^4 v^2 + 1774 u^3 v^3 + 1720 u^2 v^4 + 752 u v^5 + 128 v^6 + 
 696 u^4 v w + 2913 u^3 v^2 w + 3944 u^2 v^3 w + 2168 u v^4 w + 
 432 v^5 w + 696 u^4 w^2 + 3159 u^3 v w^2 + 5139 u^2 v^2 w^2 + 
 3378 u v^3 w^2 + 800 v^4 w^2 + 1010 u^3 w^3 + 2915 u^2 v w^3 + 
 2647 u v^2 w^3 + 792 v^3 w^3 + 574 u^2 w^4 + 985 u v w^4 + 
 413 v^2 w^4 + 150 u w^5 + 117 v w^5 + 18 w^6$$

We see that we have equality if and only if $v=w=0$, that is, $a=b=c$, or, $x=y=z=1$.

Comment: What are the expressions?

Comment: @marty cohen: Added some details, glad you asked.

Comment: Nice answer!  Could you please explain how you came up with your original substitutions for x, y, z?

Comment: That's a standard technique. If 0 < a < b < c, then you can write b = a+u, c = b+v = a+u+v where u > 0, v > 0. A multinomial in a, b, c then becomes a multinomial in a, u, v. If this multinomial has all non-negative coefficients, then it is always positive.

Comment: @user84413: Yes, the sum of $x$,$y$, $ z$ is $3$ so they are triple of some numbers with sum $1$. Now, for the numbers with sum $1$, they are some proportions.

Comment: @orangeskid  Thanks for your reply; you taught me something new.

Comment: @martycohen  Thanks for your comment.  (That part of the solution made sense, but I didn't know how to get the substitutions at the very start.)

Answer (score 0):

I would go into homogeneous coordinates,
$$A=3=x+y+z$$
$$X=2x-y-z \quad x=(A+X)/3$$
and cyclically for $Y$ and $Z$. The coordinates $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are orthogonal to $A$, so whatever their values, they respect the constraint to the plane. Additionally, $X+Y+Z=0$.

With this, the sum is rewritten:
$$\sum \frac{(A+X)^2}{2(A+Y)^2-3(A+Y)+27}=\sum\frac{9+6X+X^2}{36+3Y+2Y^2}$$
The $X=Y=Z=0$ lies on the symmetry axis, and there, the sum is exactly $\frac{3}{4}$. We now just have to prove that the function is increasing off-axis.

The denominator has no poles on the domain, so the Taylor expansion converges. Just write

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum (1+X/2+X^2/9)(1-(Y/12+Y^2/18)+(Y/12+Y^2/18)^2-(Y/12+Y^2/18)^3+\cdots)$$

and you can extract the second derivatives quite easily.

It may be a bit tricker to prove the function does not turn around and reach below the axis value, but at least you know where to start.

Comment: I like the use of homogenous coordinates. Somehow you need to use that $x$, $y$,.. are $>0$.

Comment: Perhaps you can write $x = \frac{3a}{a+b+c}$ and so on, and get a homogenous inequality in positive $a$, $b$, $c$ (also with circular symmetry).